# How do I obtain coherence length of a monochromatic laser with data about the visibility?

Tags: experimental-physics, laser, interferometry, coherence

I am using a Michelson interferometer and have obtained data about the visibility. However, I am now having trouble knowing what to plot in order to find the coherence lenghth of the laser.

I thought I had to graph visibility v/s path difference, however this does not give me anything like a Gaussian curve where I could define a coherence length as the width of the Gaussian.

Any and all help is appreciated!

[image: Image is visibility v/s path length difference]

Comment: Could you post the visibility vs optical path length difference plot? You are right that coherence length shows up as the length scale over which the visibility decreases.

Comment: I have posted the data that I currently have. Tommorrow i will get more data points, but I don't see any trend for the moment so I amcurious as to whether I am doing it properly

Comment: The data is noisy.  If you extend the path difference beyond 30, it might look more bell-shaped.  I could believe that this is a Gaussian of width around 17 cm. The noise does not help the eye here.

Comment: It might help also to know the type of laser and details of the setup.

Comment: What's the fringe size with respect to your detector? The interference pattern probably changes a lot more frequently than the sampling rate you have chosen, so you will have sampled a somewhat randomised distribution because you don't resolve the individual fringes passing your detector.